# How to reorder timestamps in multiple columns into a single column python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, merge

I am trying to sort `timestamps` across multiple `columns` in a `pandas` `df` into a single time ordered `column`.

So for the df below I'd like to combine these to create one column

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    '' : ['Bar','Foo','Fubar'],
    'A' : ['8:00','8:29','8:58'],        
    'B' : ['8:30','8:59','9:28'],            
    'C' : ['9:00','9:29','10:00'], 
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
             A     B      C
0    Bar  8:00  8:30   9:00
1    Foo  8:29  8:59   9:29
2  Fubar  8:58  9:28  10:00
```

Intended Output:

```
       1  2      3
0    Bar  1   8:00
1    Foo  1   8:29
2    Bar  2   8:30
3  Fubar  1   8:58
4    Foo  2   8:59
5    Bar  3   9:00
6  Fubar  2   9:28
7    Foo  3   9:29
8  Fubar  3  10:00
```

I can sort them via `df = df.sort_values(by='1',ascending=True)` but I need to merge them somehow. I have tried;

```
df =  df.sum(axis=1)
```

I've also tried similar joining methods but the result is always

```
0       Bar8:008:309:00
1       Foo8:298:599:29
2    Fubar8:589:2810:00
```

Update:

Using @Wen's code I get the following output

```
df.columns=['',1,2,3]
df = pd.melt(df, '')
df = df.sort_values(by='value',ascending=True)

         variable  value
8  Fubar        3  10:00 #All ordered except for the first row?
0    Bar        1   8:00
1    Foo        1   8:29
3    Bar        2   8:30
2  Fubar        1   8:58
4    Foo        2   8:59
6    Bar        3   9:00
5  Fubar        2   9:28
7    Foo        3   9:29
```

It's all ordered except for the 1st row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.columns=['',1,2,3]
df.melt('')
Out[99]: 
         variable  value
0    Bar        1   8:00
1    Foo        1   8:29
2  Fubar        1   8:58
3    Bar        2   8:30
4    Foo        2   8:59
5  Fubar        2   9:28
6    Bar        3   9:00
7    Foo        3   9:29
8  Fubar        3  10:00
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen. What version of pandas do you have. I've got 0.19.2. I'm getting an error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'

Comment: @Punter345 then you can try pd.melt i am at0.20.0

Comment: @Punter345 after melt you can apply pd.time_delta for value column , them sort_values after change

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.T.values,3,axis=1)).T
newdf.columns=df.columns
newdf['new']=list(set(df['A']))+list(set(df['B']))+list(set(df['C']))
newdf['']=newdf[''][::3].tolist()*3
newdf['n']=sorted([1,2,3]*3)
newdf=newdf[['','n','new']]
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
          n    new
0    Bar  1   8:00
1    Foo  1   8:29
2  Fubar  1   8:58
3    Bar  2   8:59
4    Foo  2   8:30
5  Fubar  2   9:28
6    Bar  3   9:00
7    Foo  3  10:00
8  Fubar  3   9:29
```

Comment: Thanks @U9-Forward. I can't seem to get this sorted though? I'm using `newdf = newdf.sort_values(by='new',ascending=True)`